# How can I get "sudo chmod +x my_script.sh" to work? (operation not permitted) (Fedora 30)

Tags: linux, shell, fedora, chmod

I am attempting to make a file `my_script.sh` executable by using the `sudo chmod +x my_script.sh` command. I created the file my_script.sh with `sudo gedit my_script.sh` I did my writing in the file, then I used `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` to save the change.
I then attempted the `sudo chmod +x my_script.sh` command, but received the output `chmod: changing permissions of '/rw/config/vpn/qubes-vpn-handler.sh': Operation not permitted`. I've looked all over the web and on these forums and have found a number of posts offering solutions about changing ownership, etc. However, these all meet with the same result. I'm including some examples below, in case they're helpful:

```
[user@---]$ sudo chmod +x my_script.sh
chmod: changing permissions of 'my_script.sh': Operation not permitted
[user@---]$ sudo chmod +x my_script.sh
chmod: changing permissions of 'my_script.sh': Operation not permitted
[user@---]$ sudo rm my_script.sh
rm: cannot remove 'my_script.sh': Operation not permitted
[user@---]$ sudo chmod 0754 my_script.sh
chmod: changing permissions of 'my_script.sh': Operation not permitted
[user@---]$ sudo chown user my_script.sh
chown: changing ownership of 'my_script.sh': Operation not permitted
[user@---]$ sudo chmod u+x my_script.sh
chmod: changing permissions of 'my_script.sh': Operation not permitted
[user@---]$ sudo rm my_script.sh
rm: cannot remove 'my_script.sh': Operation not permitted
[user@---]$ sudo chmod -R a+x /[directory containing my_script.sh]
chmod: changing permissions of 'my_script.sh': Operation not permitted
```

If anyone can render assistance I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the `chattr +i` have a look at the man page : https://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr.

It prevents any user including the root from modifying or deleting a file. You can do `chattr -i` to change that.

Comment: That solved it perfectly. My gratitude to you. It is certainly a very logical solution but I would not have thought of it on my own. Lessons for later :)